# Access to gameObject from Physics2D.Raycast and Physics2D.OverlapCircle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm curious why I can't access to gameObject directly from Physics2D.Raycast as I can do it from Physics2D.OverlapCircle. As example:

```
Collider2D topHit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(top_Collision.position, 0.2f, playerLayer);
if(topHit.gameObject.tag == "Player")
```

And for Physics2D.Raycast:

```
RaycastHit2D leftHit = Physics2D.Raycast(left_Collision.position, Vector2.left, 0.1f, playerLayer);
if (leftHit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
```

Why I have to use "collider"?

And also please guide me, how to use documentation or Microsoft Visual Studio to avoid such questions.
I mean, how can check such thing by my own - how to get to gameObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `collider` because of the return type of [Physics2D.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html). 
It returns an [RaycastHit2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D.html) and this object contains some other information than the object collider, such as the distance and other parameters you can check on the docs.

The `RaycastHit2D.collider` is of type [Collider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html), which is the same as the return type of [Physics2D.OverlapCircle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html).

You should always refer to the [Unity Scripting Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/) and check your IDE autocomplete suggestions, they usually come with documentation snippets and can you help.

Comment: But I still don't understand why I can't use gameObject directly on RaycastHit2D as I can do it on Collider2D.
What does it do that I have access to gameObject from collider?

Comment: The object must be a `Component` for it to hold a reference to `gameObject`.
`Collider2D` inherits from `Behaviour` which inherits from `Component`, while `RaycastHit2D` does not inherit from anything.

Comment: So instead of leftHit.collider I can use leftHit.rigidbody or leftHit.transform

Comment: That would be right.
Another tip, avoid comparing tags like that. Always use [CompareTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html), it's more efficient and should shorten your code, making it easier to read.